# Javascript sort array of objects by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects structured like so (this is just example) and an array of id:

```
var array_objects=[
        {id:'a',value:1},
        {id:'b',value:2},
        {id:'c',value:2},
        {id:'d',value:3}
        ];

var array =['b','c','a','d'];
```

I wish to reorder `array_objects` the same way `array` is ordered. The order in the array can change each time. How to do this?

Comment: what sort of order is this?

Comment: You could foreach loop through `array`, referencing `array_objects` to create a new, sorted, array of objects

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

```
array_objects.sort(function(a,b){
  return array.indexOf(a.id)-array.indexOf(b.id)
})
```

If you have a very big array and you want something really fast, here's a variant not calling `indexOf`:

```
var m = array.reduce(function(r,k,i){ return r[k]=i,r },{});
array_objects.sort(function(a,b){ return m[a.id]-m[b.id] });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to generate a new array.

```
var arr2 = [], i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    arr2[array.indexOf(array_objects[i].id)] = array_objects[i];
```

---

If it's important to use the same reference, you can do some magic with `splice`

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    array_objects[array.indexOf(array_objects[i].id) + array.length] = array_objects[i];
array_objects.splice(0, array.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this quite simple, try this:

```
array_objects.sort(function(a,b){
  return (a.id) > (b.id)
});
```